# Cannot draw polygons using XCB in C

Tags: c, xcb

Just started with XCB programming with C. I have written this code which will create a window and draw some points and a rectangle:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>

int main() {
    xcb_connection_t *connection = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
    if (xcb_connection_has_error(connection)) {
        printf("Error setting up connection to X\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    const xcb_setup_t *setup = xcb_get_setup(connection);
    xcb_screen_t *screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(setup).data;

    // Create wndow
    xcb_window_t window_id = xcb_generate_id(connection);
    uint32_t prop_name = XCB_CW_BACK_PIXEL | XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK;
    uint32_t prop_value[2];
    prop_value[0] = screen->white_pixel;
    prop_value[1] = XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS | XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_PRESS | XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE;
    xcb_create_window(connection, screen->root_depth, window_id, screen->root, 100, 100, 500, 400, 1,
                            XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT, screen->root_visual, prop_name, &prop_value);
    xcb_map_window(connection, window_id);
    xcb_flush(connection);

    uint32_t gc_value_mask = XCB_GC_FOREGROUND | XCB_GC_GRAPHICS_EXPOSURES;
    uint32_t gc_value_list[2];
    gc_value_list[0] = screen->black_pixel;
    gc_value_list[1] = 0;
    xcb_drawable_t drawable_window = screen->root;
    xcb_gcontext_t context_id = xcb_generate_id(connection);
    xcb_void_cookie_t cookie = xcb_create_gc(connection, context_id, drawable_window, gc_value_mask, gc_value_list);

    // Create polygons
    xcb_point_t points[5] = {{10, 10}, {10, 50}, {40, 70}, {70, 40}, {50, 10}};
    xcb_rectangle_t rect = {50, 50, 100, 50};

    // Main loop
    xcb_generic_event_t *event;
    while ((event = xcb_wait_for_event(connection))) {
        switch (event->response_type) {
            case XCB_KEY_PRESS:
                break;
            case XCB_BUTTON_PRESS:
                break;
            case XCB_EXPOSE:
                printf("Expose event called\n");
                // Draw polygons
                xcb_poly_point(connection, XCB_COORD_MODE_ORIGIN, drawable_window, context_id, 4, points);
                xcb_poly_fill_rectangle(connection, drawable_window, context_id, 1, &rect);
                xcb_flush(connection);
            default:
                break;
        }
        free(event);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It has compiled properly and there was no warning or error at runtime. But, I just get a window with no graphics. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get an expose event?

Comment: Yes, I get it. After the program is launched and whenever I resize the window, `Expose event called` gets printed in the terminal, which shows that the expose event gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `xcb_poly_fill_rectangle()`, etc., are trying to draw on the root window. At least, you're passing `screen->root` as the `drawable` argument. It works for me if I pass `window_id` here.

I'm really not sure why XCB needs all these various context arguments, and the exact functions of each do not seem to be well-documented.

Comment: Which argument are you confused about? context_id is a graphics context ID (GC) or the equivalent of a windows HDC

Comment: @user253751 -- no, it's fair enough I guess. I'm more used to this kind of context information being passed around in objects, or at least in `struct`s. Heaps of numeric handles is just so 90s.

Comment: It's a network protocol. Will you send the entire context data to the server every time you draw?

Comment: @user253751 -- I'd kind of expect the library to take care of this low-level stuff, and I'd just work on a data structure that encapsulated the context. That's how GTK works, for example. I'm not saying that the XCB way is wrong or worse, merely that I've got out of the habit of working at that level.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin Boone is correct: You are drawing to the root window.

I did the following change to your program (it is the same one that Kevin suggested):

```
--- t.c.orig    2020-09-18 15:06:38.344441255 +0200
+++ t.c 2020-09-18 15:06:48.104167556 +0200
@@ -26,7 +26,7 @@ int main() {
     uint32_t gc_value_list[2];
     gc_value_list[0] = screen->black_pixel;
     gc_value_list[1] = 0;
-    xcb_drawable_t drawable_window = screen->root;
+    xcb_drawable_t drawable_window = window_id;
     xcb_gcontext_t context_id = xcb_generate_id(connection);
     xcb_void_cookie_t cookie = xcb_create_gc(connection, context_id, drawable_window, gc_value_mask, gc_value_list);
```

This results in the following window contents being shown. You can see both the rectangle and the individual pixels being shown:

[image]

Please do not accept this answer, but instead Kevin Boone's. I only wanted to add the screenshot.

Comment: That's very generous of you :)